# Not able to send different callback parameter from multiple child components (same component) to parent

Tags: reactjs

Parent component is calling multiple children (same type) with different labels for differentiating child in setting state in callback function. But the 'handleCheckbox' in parent components is always recieving label parameter value of first child 'Include Prefix' only, even when clicking second switch. Verified that label is correctly passed to the child components.

Children calls from Parent -

```
  const [prefixChecked, setPrefixChecked] = useState(false);
  const [suffixChecked, setSuffixChecked] = useState(false);
  const [middleNameChecked, setMiddleNameChecked] = useState(false);


<ToggleSwitch
          checked={prefixChecked}
          handleCheckbox={handleCheckbox}
          label="Include Prefix"
        />
<ToggleSwitch
          checked={suffixChecked}
          handleCheckbox={handleCheckbox}
          label="Include Suffix"
        />
```

Parent Callback function and finally the child component -

```
 const handleCheckbox = (label) => {
    console.log("label", label);
    switch (label) {
      case "Include Prefix":
        setPrefixChecked((prevChecked) => !prevChecked);
        break;
      case "Include Suffix":
        setSuffixChecked((prevChecked) => !prevChecked);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };      
                                                                                                                                                                               

export const ToggleSwitch = ({ label, checked, handleCheckbox }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <span style={{ paddingRight: "1rem" }}>{label} : </span>
      <input
        checked={checked}
        onChange={() => handleCheckbox(label)}
        className="react-switch-checkbox"
        id={`react-switch-new`}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label className="react-switch-label" htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}>
        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: please can you share useState code lines. this is very odd.

Comment: Included now in the first code section. It is odd i have been using same through map function generally multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this was happening because the id in input and htmlFor in label were same for all the elements. Now i have mapped it to different labels.

```
<input
        checked={checked}
        onChange={() => handleCheckbox(label)}
        className="react-switch-checkbox"
        id={label}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label className="react-switch-label" htmlFor={label}>
        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
```